# What is wrong with my datetime object code?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I don't know what is wrong with this code:

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(row, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    AddTo(timestamp)
```

Date time string I am reading in from a .csv file:

```
'25/02/2021 15:18'
```

I keep getting an error saying the format is invalid - Please can someone give me a hint of what is wrong? I'm not after the complete code :)

Comment: You specified a format with seconds, but in the example from the csv file there are no seconds. Have you checked that?

Comment: I changed it to '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' and it still throws an error

Comment: I tested my suggestion and it worked fine...

Comment: Look I fixed it

Comment: the data has no seconds component

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.strptime('25/02/2021 15:18', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
print(timestamp)
```

Your previous mistake was including the second.

There could be other error such as some formatting issue in your file or check your AddTo function. Check that you are using `from datetime import datetime` rather than `import datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You have seconds in the row you're trying to read, but not in the representative string that parses the date and time. Knowing nothing else about your code, we can only really answer about the line where the variable `timestamp` is assigned.

When I put this into my Python interpreter, it seems to work okay:
`timestamp = datetime.strptime('25/02/2021 15:18', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

So you are going to want this:

`timestamp = datetime.strptime(row, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in reader:
            fix = str(row)
            fix2 = fix[2:-2]
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(fix2, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
            arrayy.append(timestamp)
```

My CSV was coming from Oracle SQL and contained quotes around the extracted time stamps. I had to remove the first and last char from my time string.

SORRY I wasn't aware there were quotes!

Comment: note that you can always edit your question to add more details. for example here, you should also specify what `reader` is - basically try to create a [mre]. and regarding debugging, a simple `print` is sometimes all it takes ;-)